# How to set desktop background in terminal with osascript?

Tags: osascript

I can change desktop background successfully in Script Editor with the following code.

```
tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/path/3Q83dROp3Fk.jpg"
```

But the following code in terminal doesn't work

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"/path/3Q83dROp3Fk.jpg\""
```

Save the script file as `1.scpt` and run the `osascript 1.scpt` returns `1.scpt: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)`

System: macOS High Sierra.